# Simulating samples from Gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I'm having trouble with a programming assignment.

From the previous questions, I have a `list` of 49 elements.

Each element is `sample` data of `size=10000`. For the last question, I have to calculate the mean of the first `n` sample values.

- With `n` between **one** and **ten thousand**, within each dataset.

I then have to plot these running averages for each data set.

I've been trying to create lists/vectors of the running averages but it's not working out.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: So, do you need 49 mean values? Is n equal for all 49 datasets?

Comment: For each data set, I have to get a running mean, so for one sample, for example, I have to get the mean of the first number, then the mean of the first 2 numbers and so on until I get to 10000. I then have to plot these means on a graph and repeat for the other 48 datasets. I hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 3):

Function for running average:

```
run_avg <- function(x, n_max){
a <- c(1:n_max)
r_avg <- sapply(a, FUN = function(y) mean(x[1:y]))
return(r_avg) 
}
```

In your case, n_max should equal 10000;
This function then creates, for one dataset, the running averages.

This has then to be applied to all datasets. You could use lapply for this, if your datasets are stored within a list. Another approach could be a loop or something like that.

Edit: I see that your datasets are in a list, so simply use:

```
lapply(my_list, run_avg, n_max = 10000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The running averages can be computed with the following.

```
res <- lapply(x, function(y){
  sapply(seq_along(y), function(k) mean(y[1:k]))
})
```

Then in order to have the resulting list in a format better for plotting with package `ggplot2`, format it as a data frame first, with the row names as a column.

```
df_res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, res)
names(df_res) <- paste("Mean", seq_len(ncol(df_res)), sep = ".")
df_res <- cbind(df_res, id = as.integer(row.names(df_res)))
```

Now reshape from wide to long and plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_res %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Mean"),
    names_to = "Vector",
    values_to = "Mean"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(id, Mean, colour = Vector)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**Test data.**

```
set.seed(1234)

list_size <- 4  # 49 in the question
samp_size <- 20 # 10000 in the question

x <- lapply(seq.int(list_size), function(i) rgamma(samp_size, shape = i))
```